# integrate existing wordpress php blog into existing coldfusion site

Tags: php, wordpress, coldfusion, blogs

We have an existing wordpress.com blog and its url uses different host to our existing domain, blog.site.com. We want to move the blog into our existing e-commerce site that is hosted on our own servers and uses ColdFusion, www.site.com. We want the new address of the blog to be www.site.com/blog. Is this possible?

Suppose, we create a new server and install PHP on it, is it possible to keep our e-commerce site on a Coldfusion server and have users access them from the same domain and host?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. If you want to run a PHP based blog you have to run PHP somewhere. Changing the URL isn't going to change that it can be attacked. I'm not very familiar with ColdFusion but in Apache it would be possible to use a reverse proxy to change the URL. Again that does nothing for security.  If you mean that you want the blog to be accessible on your internal network only then you would need to host it on a server in your network that's not accessible from the outside world.

Comment: Instead of comments, you should improve the Question...

Comment: cross-reference to duplicate post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456177/integrate-wordpress-into-coldfusion-site-using-reverse-proxy-arr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words, you want to manage the blog content with Wordpress, but display the blog content using ColdFusion. And you don't want the Wordpress software accessible to the public.

You'd have to create a ColdFusion data source and point it to the database that's being used by Wordpress. I'm sure it's a simple task to read the entry table from there.

You can also consider moving to a ColdFusion based Content Management System.

http://www.getmura.com/

http://www.gocontentbox.org/

Both of these can import data from Wordpress. Then you'd just deploy them as applications under the /blog/ route and you're ready to go.

Comment: thanks, I would prefer to move it to a cf blog platform but our marketing team is very committed to sticking with wordpress.

Comment: I get that, but if you're not going to display anything via the Wordpress templates, why keep it around?

Answer (score 1):

It's not very difficult to change the URL a wordpress blog is hosted at. That's a matter of configuration settings in Wordpress and possibly some .htaccess

Like iKnowKungFoo just stated, it would be a bit of a task to use Coldfusion to read from the Wordpress tables and output the blog content. In essence you'd be creating a stripped down Coldfusion version of Wordpress.

Your best bet IMHO would be to migrate to MURA CMS (http://www.getmura.com) and use that instead. Mura is a very capable CMS (it's even PCI compliant) and while no CMS is entirely invulnerable, it certainly wouldn't get caught up in the constant attacks seen with Wordpress sites.

Answer (score 1):

For our clients we use both WordPress and MangoBlog - open source Coldfusion. 
Both blog engines have excellent SEO performance.

If I am not mistaken, MangoBlog imports from WordPress. You could install MangoBlog in a subdirectory /blog/ import posts/pages and adopt the few layout files to match with the other design of the site. 
You definitely need to take care of the different URLs and implement a 301 redirect that takes care of links and search engine pages.